# Java Swing : Basic understanding of JComponent / JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel, awt, jcomponent

I have the following code:

```
public class OpaqueExample {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            OpaqueFrame frame = new OpaqueFrame();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            frame.setVisible(true);
        }
    });
}

}

class OpaqueFrame extends JFrame {

private static final long serialVersionUID = 5486007826709615846L;

public OpaqueFrame() {
    super("Opacity Demo");
    this.setSize(200, 200);
    JComponent boxPanel = new BoxComponent(50, 50);
    this.add(boxPanel);
}

}

class BoxComponent extends JComponent {

private static final long serialVersionUID = -1935449999922455838L;

public BoxComponent(int x, int y) {
    super();
    this.setSize(x, y);
    this.setLocation(40, 40);
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
}

}
```

In simplicity:
a. Created a frame of size 200, 200
b. Created a Box component of size 50,50
c. Set the location of the box component 40, 40 from the top left corner of frame. Box componet is red color

When i run it, i expect to see a smaller red box in the frame container. Did i get this right or i  just don't understand the basic of swing component (seems to be the case).

Please help.
Thank.

Comment: You might want to read this: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
frame.setLayout(null);
```

or

`setLayout(null);` in the frame's constructor

This allows you to define the position of components directly

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
}
```

This should be changed to

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(Color.red);
    g.fillRect(0, 0, getWidth(), getHeight());
}
```

Info on the graphics class:
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html

Comment: What actually happens? (you posted the expected result, but not the actual)

Comment: i added the setlayout(null) in the frame constructor. However the red color box is not painted on the frame.

Comment: You're not actually drawing a box in your paintComponent. (see my edit)

Comment: OMG! It works! So the setColor is not actually filling in the color in the component. Swing is tough! Real tough! Thx

Comment: setColor sets the current colour of the Graphics object. It is the color that is to be used for all Graphics operations until set again. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html This might be useful

Comment: Thx. Now i will get back to the opacity problem. :OP

Comment: `Don't use a null layout` - Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. You have been given a link to the Swing tutorial on layout managers.

Comment: @camickr The requirement to place a 50x50 box at 40, 40 is also not was Swing was designed for. However if that is the question, then a null layout is the way to do it. 

yapkm01: the class you provided will still work under a layout, the location and size that you provide it will be more or less ignored. The object will still have a size though, and the paintComponent method will work exactly as is.

Comment: @Cruncher There isn't enough context to suggest whether the OP needs to use components at absolute locations or paint boxes at specific locations, which the OP is (essentially) doing both. So while I won't argue your approach works, there are, possibly, better solutions available.  Also, the OP isn't calling `super.paintComponent`, this WILL come back to haunt them when they start expanding the complexity of their UI

Answer (score 2):

There isn't enough context to provide a complete answer.

This is simply another possible solution to your problem....

If your intention is to try and place a component at a specific position, then why not just set its background color instead of trying to fill it using custom painting?

If you intention is to paint lots of little squares, then you don't need a separate component for each...

Swing is designed to utilise the layout manager API, it's at the core of how the framework works.

While I'll be the first to admit there are times a `null` layout is useful, I'd try a lot of things first (personally).

The following example uses a single component, but allows you to draw multiple boxes onto at varying positions and sizes...

[image]

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;

public class GraphicsExample {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new GraphicsExample();
    }

    public GraphicsExample() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                TestPane tp = new TestPane();
                tp.add(50, 50, 40, 40);

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(tp);
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }

        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private List<Rectangle> boxes;

        public TestPane() {
            boxes = new ArrayList<Rectangle>(25);
        }

        public void add(int x, int y, int width, int height) {
            boxes.add(new Rectangle(x, y, width, height));
            repaint();
        }

        @Override
        public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
            return new Dimension(200, 200);
        }

        @Override
        protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
            super.paintComponent(g);
            Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();
            g2d.setColor(Color.RED);
            for (Rectangle box : boxes) {
                g2d.fill(box);
            }
            g2d.dispose();
        }        
    }    
}
```

One of the other things you are doing wrong is not honouring the paint chain.  When you override one of the `paint` methods, you must call `super.paintXxx` to ensure that the paint chain isn't broken.  This methods do a lot of important work and are very unforgiving if you forget to include them ;)

Check out [Performing Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/) for more details